# What is the equivalent of 'template' on Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

With Vue2 I have [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template) property with allows me to render html from string:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: "<h1>Title</h1>"
})
```

I use this property to load template from a separate `.pug` file with webpack loader.

How I can do it with Vue3 ? I don't find any documentation about how render template from string.

Comment: It shouldn't have changed. `template` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template property hasn't changed but to mount a Vue app you need to use the `mount` method.

```js
Vue.productionTip = false;

const vm = Vue.createApp({
setup() {
    const msg = Vue.ref('Hello World !');
    return {
      msg
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Test : {{ msg }}
    </div>
  `
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was that I'm importing default Vue file and I need to import `vue.esm-bundler.js` ([doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#with-a-bundler)). Now it works.